# TypeError: (0 , _typography.scale) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, typeerror, typography

I use for my project Next.js and Typography.

I receive the error `TypeError: (0, _typography.scale) is not a function` and, unfortunately, don't understand why.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import typography, { rhythm, scale } from '../utils/typography';
import colors from '../utils/colors';

const HeaderLink = {
  ...scale(-1/4),
  marginRight: rhythm(1),
  color: colors.gunsmoke
}

export default () => (
  <header>
      <a style={HeaderLink} href="/#top">Home</a>
  </header>
)
```